# Sublime text2 shortcut to run PHPUnit quickly

Tags: phpunit, sublimetext

I run phpunit quite often after changing code.

And, it is always hard for me to run phpunit by clicking right button of mouse and select run phpunit.

Is there a quicker way to run it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create what is called a Build System - this way you can hit `⌘` + `B` (or Ctrl on windows) and it will run it.

Something like this will do:

https://gist.github.com/baghayi/4534089

[Read the docs](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) on how to customize the build system